# Implement Adsense Matched Content with DFP

Tags: adsense, banner, responsive, google-dfp

I want to implement the Adsense Matched Content in a website using DFP, but I don't know which type of Ad Unit I need to create.

The Matched Content tag is responsive, and I don't know which fixed size I need to create.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: @MuratÇorlu unfortunately no...